# Is there a way to get the union of `ps a` and `ps x`?

Tags: docker, ps, nohup

I would like the union of the processes returned by `ps a` and the processes returned by `ps x`.  When using Docker and nohup, it feels like one or the other of them works, but neither always shows the process I want.

`ps ax` lists *all* processes. `ps` produces those with both the non-`a` **and** non-`x` filters.  I would like the set with the non-`a` **or** non-`x` filters (removing overlaps)

In other words, I would like to list all the processes that either belong to me or have a tty.

Answer (score 2):

Do both, then sort with the unique option:

```
(ps a; ps x) | sort -ur
```

I then filtered out some of the noise. This may remove bash, sort, etc. commands you are looking for:

```
(ps a; ps x) | sort -ur | grep -v "bash$\|sort$\|ps \|sshd:"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I get what you mean, taking a stab at this I came up with the following:

```
ps -eo user,pid,tty,pcpu,pmem,etime,args | grep -E "${USER}|\ pts|\ tty"
```

Now, it's far from perfect, but I like the -eo output filtering as you can customize the columns. Might even suggest adding "ppid" in there in case you're tracking down a group of processes.

Comment: I like this answer because it demonstrates the options of ps, but I like my answer for its simplicity within the larger bash framework -- fewer ps options to remember!